# Windows phone 8 Custom message box issues

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am using custom message box from Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit assembly.

I am have an issue here with respect to the Dismissed event.

```
         var emControl = new EmailAddressUserControl();
         var messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
         {
             IsFullScreen = false,
             Caption = AppResources.AppResources.SettingTitle4,
             LeftButtonContent = AppResources.AppResources.Ok,
             RightButtonContent = AppResources.AppResources.Cancel,
             Content = emControl
         };
        messageBox.Dismissed += async (s1, e1) =>
        {
            switch (e1.Result)
            {
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                    bool isValidEmail = emControl.finishButton_Click();
                    if (isValidEmail)
                    {
                        string TempVarUserEmail = SharedProperties.EmailId.Value;
                        SharedProperties.EmailId.Value = emControl.getUserEmail();
                        ifEmailUpdate = await UpdateEmail();
                        if (ifEmailUpdate)
                        {
                            _instance.subTbEmailAddr.Text = SharedProperties.EmailId.Value;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // restoring user email address if updation failed.
                            SharedProperties.EmailId.Value = TempVarUserEmail;
                            MessageBox.Show("Email updation failed. Try again later", "Email update failed!!!", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Email address", "Invalid email address!!!", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                    }
                    break;
            }
        };
```

I have a textbox in my EmailAddressUserControl which basically takes email address and when i click on OK on the message box it checks the validity of the email address...

The problem i have right now is that, if its not valid, it will show  up the regular message box in the else condition and when i click on OK on that messatge box, even the custom message box is dismissed.

Is there a way to override this ? Can i have the message to still be present even after clicking on OK? I know i am validating the email address on the OK button click and it is in the dismissed event handler, i think its a bad way of doing it.

I am open to any ideas and criticisms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I got what you asked. Can you just open the custom message box again if the user clicks OK on the "Invalid email address" message box?

```
        MessageBoxResult msg = MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Email address", "Invalid email address!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        if (msg == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            //OK Clicked
            //Open up the custom messsage box here again
        }
```